# making xaxis values selectable in a d3js code

Tags: javascript, select, d3.js

[This is my code](http://vida.io/documents/Wi8TZCjy7p6Az6yZv) I have xaxis1 that contains months names: January..December.
I want to make evry month value selectable so I add this function :

```
d3.select(".xAxis1") //selecting xAxis1 division
.selectAll(".major")  //select all the tiket defined on it
.on("click",clickMe)  //applay the function on clik to each value

 function clickMe(){alert("I've been clicked!")}
```

But it is not working?!! any ideas?

Comment: what are the select and selectAll? are they syntax of jquery?

Comment: syntax in d3js select to select a devision givin by his name and select all to select the tikets in the axis but I am not quite sure that have used them in a proper way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not good in d3js but why you are not trying.

```
d3.select(".xAxis1") //selecting xAxis1 division
.on("click",clickMe);  //applay the function on clik to each value

d3.selectAll(".major")  //select all the tiket defined on it
.on("click",clickMe)  //applay the function on clik to each value

 function clickMe(){alert("I've been clicked!")}
```

and as I took a look at your code I think the `".xAxis1"` is not correct and it should be 
`".axis1"`

Comment: Thank you it was a small mistake I introduced the name of the axis in the select function not the name of the class...Thank you you let my pay attention to my mistake :) but my code is fine because I dont want to make the axis selectable, only the ticket on it.

Comment: I'm cheking the link. and I'm from Iran and nice to meet you. and are you a Muslim?

Comment: yes.. Have you an idea how to display only the month name instead of all the date?

Comment: I'm not good ind3js and I learn it just from your codes so I think I can't help you more and I should leave now sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If some one need the same thing this the code:
http://vida.io/documents/LD3gAW64tv5yYj3yf

Comment: I checked that link but it says its has been removed or its not shared.